# DB2 removing white spaces in field values

Tags: db2

In a table I have a column called column_xml defined as CLOB(1000000). The fields in the column contain XML formatted information. My problem is that there are lots of white spaces in these fields that I need to get remove if there are more than 3 whitespaces in a row.

This is what the output looks like now

```
column_xml                                                                       
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<values>                                                                      
 <comment>test test test                               </comment>
 <rights></rights>                                                            
 <title>TEST MAN                                            </title>                                         
</values>                                                                     
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

How can I remove all the white spaces before `</comment>` and `</title>` so it looks like this?

```
column_xml                                                                       
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<values>                                                                      
 <comment>test test test</comment>
 <rights></rights>                                                            
 <title>TEST MAN</title>                                         
</values>                                                                     
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

If you define your XML document in a XML column, you can control how the whitespaces are stored.

For XML parsing, you can take a look a this page: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r5/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.xml.doc/doc/c0023533.html

To define the XML Schema, and how the whitespaces should be treated: http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_facets.asp

However, you are using a LOB and you are not exploiting the hybrid motor of DB2.

Comment: I suggest you replace that link to w3fools with a link to [IBM DB2 doc pages](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2.luw.xml.doc%2Fdoc%2Fc0022308.html)

Comment: I put a IBM DB2 link, however, I left the w3schools for XML defining. IBM DOC does not gives those clues.

Comment: I cannot judge this specific w3schools page but I have often found many mistakes in other pages of theirs (like in SQL ones.) Is there no official XML site that has info about this?

Comment: Well, the official documentation comes from W3C: http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/ (Section 4.3.6 Facets>Whitespace) However this documentation is very complex, and difficult to solve a simple problem at an entry level.

Answer (score -1):

I think this can be done with a simple replace:

```
UPDATE {table} set {field} = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE({field}, '   ', ''), '  ', ''), ' </', '</')
```

With the input:

```
<values>                                                                      
 <comment>test test test                               </comment>
 <rights></rights>                                                            
 <title>TEST MAN                                            </title>                                         
</values>
```

Gives the result:

```
<values> 
 <comment>test test test</comment>
 <rights></rights>
 <title>TEST MAN</title>
</values>
```

Comment: I think `TRIM({field})` is a better and faster choice.